# How to debug on a real device (using Eclipse/ADT)

Tags: android, debugging, device, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm trying to figure out how to debug applications directly on my phone (HTC Desire).

I've installed the USB driver that came with the phone and the phone is listed when using "adb devices".

How do I configure eclipse/ADT to launch on the phone instead of launching the emulator/virtual device?

Answer (score 78):

Note: This answer is a heavily modified version of [this guide that used to exist at developer.android.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20120130201430/http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).  Portions of it are quoted verbatim from the original text without attribution for the specific parts that are quoted.

---

With an Android-powered device, you can develop and debug your Android applications just as you would on the emulator.

**1. Declare your application as "debuggable" in `AndroidManifest.xml`.**

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    ... >
    ...
</application>
```

**2. On your handset, navigate to Settings > Security and check `Unknown sources`**

[image]

**3. Go to Settings > Developer Options and check `USB debugging`**
*Note that if `Developer Options` is invisible you will need to navigate to Settings > About Phone and tap on `Build number` several times until you are notified that it has been unlocked.*

[image]

**4. Set up your system to detect your device.**
*Follow the instructions below for your OS:*

---

## Windows Users

*Install the Google USB Driver from the ADT SDK Manager

(Support for: ADP1, ADP2, Verizon Droid, Nexus One, Nexus S).*

[image]

*For devices not listed above, [install an OEM driver for your device](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)*

---

## Mac OS X

*Your device should automatically work; Go to the next step*

---

## Ubuntu Linux

*Add a `udev` rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, [click here](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers). To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:*

1. Log in as root and create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.
2. Use this format to add each vendor to the file:
   `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`
   *In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.*
3. Now execute: `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the [udev documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/udev) ***for your system*** as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, [see this guide to writing udev rule](https://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)s.

---

**5. Run the project with your connected device.**

***With Eclipse/ADT:** run or debug your application as usual. You will be presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s).*

***With ADB:** issue commands with the -d flag to target your connected device.*

Comment: List of USB vendor IDs (for udev config): https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html I'm just including this because Samsung has at least 4 PCI vendor ID, and in the PCI vendor ID database 0x04E8 is listed as "Samsung Windows Portable Devices". However that should be the USB vendor ID, whatever that means now.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes you need to reset ADB.
To do that, in Eclipse, go:

Window>>
Show View >> 
Android
(Might be found in the "Other" option)>>Devices

in the device Tab, click the down arrow, and choose reset adb.

Comment: I didn't see my device and reset adb has helped. Thank you!

Comment: I got this error message: [2013-09-29 23:02:25 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 1):

in devices which has Android 4.3 and above you should follow these steps:

How to enable Developer Options:

```
Launch Settings menu.
Find the open the ‘About Device’ menu.
Scroll down to ‘Build Number’.
Next, tap on the ‘build number’ section seven times.
After the seventh tap you will be told that you are now a developer.
Go back to Settings menu and the Developer Options menu will now be displayed.
```

In order to enable the USB Debugging you will simply need to open Developer Options, scroll down and tick the box that says ‘USB Debugging’. That’s it.