# How do you push an android app to your phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just don't know how to do it.  I'm using the newest version of eclipse Juno and need to push the app (or email it) to my MyTouch.  How would I do it from eclipse, as that is the way I would prefer?  If I should just email it, would I email the whole project folder or just a particular piece of code?

Comment: Have you considered reading the related documentation? Its available on http://developer.android.com/

Comment: Can't you just run your app...?  That'll put it on the phone.

Comment: If you are trying to install your android app on your phone and debug it, I suggest you have a look at this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt)

Comment: Like the others havea said you can run the app directly on your phone using the links posted by @HansHohenfeld. If for whatever that does not work, then you can simply create the apk file, put it onto something like Dropbox and then using the dropbox app install it onto your phone like any other app by simply clicking on the apk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for : 
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

After proper installation, right click on your project and click "Run as android application" while your phone is pluged to your computer by USB.