# First time exporting app from PC --> Android

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I just tried to export a few sample apps I made onto my device.  I already enabled USB debugging, but I am not sure what to do once I do File > Export under the eclipse menu.  I made a keystore and from there I thought the app would be ready to go on my device but I was wrong.  If anyone has any insight as to what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:  More specifically what is the "Destination APK location"

Comment: what do u mean by exporting..do you want to run/debug your application on the device?

Comment: Check this answer for usb debugging apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt

Comment: I guess my question was not worded correctly.  I am not looking to debug, I am looking to physically load the app onto my device to turn in as an assignment.

Comment: i guess you are trying to create your apk file which is uploadable for Google play ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package

And then you select your keystore and then it should create your .apk - file which you can load on your phone.

And you can also select where the destination of your .apk will be.

Comment: but where do I put this .apk file to actually get it physically on my device?  New to android in general so I am having issues with this part.

Comment: You just have to do this part I wrote above and then a frame appears where you select you keystore and your password for it. And at least you can select the destination for your apk file. And from there you can put it on your device. If it's on your device, move to it's destionation and install it. Solved this your problem?

Comment: and where would this destination for the APK file be appropriately placed?  I tried to move it where the youtube, maps, currents, etc were located but I still do not see the app on my device.

Comment: Do you mean on your device? If yes, it would be the best you make a new folder where you put all your selfmade apk files in it. And download ES File Explorer on you device, from there you go to this folder and then install it. That's the process I do it.

Comment: And is this under Android > Data > ??  once this issue is solved you will get my up vote and correct answer.

Comment: Just make a new folder where all other folders are. you can create it also in a other folder. It makes no difference. Just copy you apk in one folder and install it after.

Answer (score 0):

You could start your app on your device by pressing CTRL + F11.

Please make sure that your device is connected to PC and USB drivers are installed.