# Can't able to run PhoneGap app in Android device

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I have created a test PhoneGap Android App through CLI - I can able to run it to emulator but I can't able to run it to a device which is connected to through USB.

USB debugging is also enabled.

```
> adb devices
```

doesn't list the device but which lists the emulator.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Follw this link for debug with device in android
1) http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt

Comment: It's likely that you are missing the adb driver for your device. The default google driver only works for few devices. For some brands there are pre-built packages, and sometimes you have to modify the google driver's inf files and installed the driver as unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB driver for the device was missing. For some of the Google devices drivers are available in sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. For other brands like HTC, Samsung and others we need to get it from them and install the same. I have downloaded driver for HTC One X from their website and installed it.

Sources:

- [Using hardware devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)
- [Install USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

After installation use the below command to run the PhoneGap app

```
cordova run android \\if project created with cordova command

phonegap run android \\if project created with phonegap command
```