# Doesn't run phonegap app on samsung device?

Tags: cordova

I have created a test PhoneGap Android App through CLI - I can able to run it to emulator but I can't able to run it to a device which is connected to through USB. My device is samsung verizon CDMA model no-SCH_I200.

I also followed link: [Can't able to run PhoneGap app in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728062/cant-able-to-run-phonegap-app-in-android-device).

USB debugging is also enabled.

> adb devices

doesn't list the device but which lists the emulator.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Install kies http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/ . I faced same issue, hope it may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't able to run PhoneGap app in Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728062/cant-able-to-run-phonegap-app-in-android-device)

Comment: Hey Ved It doesn't support my device that is samsung SCH-I200 verizon cdma phone.

Comment: Hey All its done!!!!...

Comment: Ok.........good....!

Comment: @Ved can you upvote the question?. NidhiSavani needs to have atleast 10 reputations to upload an image. I have upvoted her question, which added 5 points to her account.

Answer (score 0):

If `adb` is failing to list the devices, then the problem doesn't come from Cordova, it is very likely that you have the wrong USB driver (I assume you correctly activated the developers mode on your Android).

Make sure you installed this USB driver correctly: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Open Device Manager (start menu > run > `devmgmt.msc`). Make sure your Samsung is listed as an ADB Interface. If you still see your device as a Samsung SCH_I200 then the drivers arent correctly installed.

[image: ADB]

Comment: I installed driver for that and done that u gave a link already but didn't work for me. What i have to do?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and done steps gave first in given link. but i can't find the option "Android Phone" in right pane which is given into 4th step in 'or' part of steps. Is the problem from here?

Comment: hi @NidhiSavani, can you open the Device Manager and check if your device is listed as using the `Android Composite ADB Interface`. I updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: hello, here i want to tell you that i am not getting the Android Device at all. I am getting portable device and in it i m finding my device that is SCH-I200. how to show you screen shot? Please help. I am new in this also.

Comment: I am not able to show you screenshot because i am very new to stackoverflow also. so it giving me an error for no sufficient reputation for uploading image. I am sorry for this. But actually not getting Android Device in device manager please help.

Comment: @NidhiSavani You need to **edit** your question to add an image. When you edit your question there will an **image** icon at the top of the edit box, which you have to click and upload the image.

Comment: Thanx frank but i am not able for uploading image because of raputation need atleast 10 points so.

Comment: @NidhiSavani can  you try to answer your own question and may be you will get to add an image in the answer.

Comment: @NidhiSavani We have upvoted your question. Now you more than 10 reputation. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @NidhiSavani. If you have solved the issue, than you need to post your answer(explaining how the problem was solved), so that it would be helpful to those who visit your question.

Comment: Hey all, visit this link samsung users for download drivers and connection between pc and devics.  samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES . It works for me.. Thanx ved....