# Breakpoints are skipped

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

I'm using ADT,and a real device. I start the app with: debug as -> android native application

The app starts and then I'm prompted to move to the debug view,I go there,and I see see a list of threads,but none of my breakpoints ever gets hit. Some ideeas?

Comment: Check if this other question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt

Comment: checked the options,tried reseting adb and still nothing...

Comment: Is the debug mode enable on your real device?