# How to console cordova applications in browser

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

This is the first time, I am working on `cordova` applications. I created a dummy application as per documentation and tested in simulator working fine.

Now I made an `.APK` file and installed in my own `android` device, there also working fine. Whenever I am modified anything, I have to make `APK` file and re-installing... these everything taking time for my development.So I decided to test application directly in my device instead of simulator. I Goggled and found [URL-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714400/how-to-debug-on-a-real-device-using-eclipse-adt) [URL-2](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-debugging-on-real-device/), They are suggesting,we can overcome this with USB cable. As per their suggestions I did it, now directly I am running application into my device(I mean no need to make APK file).

Note : I am using `Eclipse,windows7` for my development.

Until now, this was fine, but the problem I am not able to console . If I test my application with `simulators` I can console in browser using `chrome tools`, that way I can identify what going wrong. I can put breakpoints there and I can debug.

I don't want to test with simulators(I want to test directly with my devices), but I can't able to see console If I test with my own device.

Regarding this, I searched but I didn't find any solutions. can anyone help me.

Basically

1. I want to test my application directly with my device(don't want to test with simulators)
2. I want to console

I did first point with USB, I didn't find any way for my second point. can anyone help me .

Thanks.

Comment: If you debug your apps on device using chrome-tools you will need android4.4 version mobile. and refer this it's may be helpful for you http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/

Comment: @prabhu I am using `gapDebug` app to debug my cordova application. It's very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options: The easiest option is to use alerts instead of console logs. This is a little annoying still since you potentially get a bunch of alerts, but it's definitely better than rebuilding and/or redeploying your cordova application every time you want to test something.

If you are set on using `console.log()`, you need to install `abd` and use `logcat`. For information on setting this up, check this url:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Debugging/On-device_console_logging

You can run this command in your terminal to output the logs once you have installed abd:

`abd logcat`

Comment: did you work on `NFC` based apps, If you worked, I have a small doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `gapDebug` app to debug my applications. It's very simple.

Comment: @prabhu I think, you work on `nfc` Apps. can you look this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688456/my-cordova-application-not-launching-after-nfc-tag-detect`

Comment: now i am  not working on that.I need your contact mail address if you can let me know? cfprabhu@yahoo.com